# Here SDK - Is it possible to create a GPX file during a simulated navigation?

Tags: here-api

The rerouting operation is one of the most important features in a Gps app and the apps are generally not suitable for my needs about the rerouting. This is one of the reasons I'm using the Here Api.

Unfortunately, there is no setting to manage the behaviour of the rerouting except... pausing or stopping the navigation. That can work but it's quite difficult to see what exactly happens, to see the order of the operations when resuming or restarting the navigation. This is why it's very intersting to use GPX files to simulate the followed route.

And so, it should very instersting to create GPX files when simulating a navigation instead of creating a file when driving, walking, ...

Moreover, some tools like mapstogpx are able to create GPX files but without time, speed and hdop data. And it seems that Here api need these data to play back a log file.

Could you confirm that is not possible to record a GPX file when simulating a navigation? Do you know a suitable solution?

That apart, I would like to mention that the speed alarm seems to be automatically enabled when resuming a navigation or, maybe, starting a new navigation. However, when starting or resuming a navigation, I always use setSpeedWarningEnabled(false). This setting looks like a toggle.

Here SDK Version: 3.13.2.86 / Android 9.0

Comment: In fact, the speed and the hdop data are not necessary to play a GPX file with the PositionSimulator. But the time field is aboslutely needed. Otherwise the playback is very very quick and useless to make a test ! So the current solution is a recording of a GPX file in real conditions or, using mapstogpx tool, to add time data in the GPX file.

Answer (score 0):

The HERE Mobile SDK does provide method to create GPX logs but it would not work in simulation mode , it would create logs in actual navigation mode ([documentation](https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/dev_guide/topics/map-positioning.html)) which guessing from the comment above, you already reached that conclusion.

You could use any mock gps app to simulate a route when the SDK is in navigation mode to generate a GPS file which could be played back with the PositionSimulator.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm using mapstogpx which works with a Google Maps url and I add the time data programatically in the GPX file that I get. A part of this file should be also deleted in order to be played by Here PositionSimulator.